# Cannot get two android emulators connectable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I create one socket server on AE1, and then create a client on AE2. I want to access the server on AE1 from AE2. So I follow the [introduction](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking). And still cannot get it work.

I understand that I should let the server in AE1 listen on `10.0.2.15:8080`, and then I use `redir add tcp:8080:8080` command in AE1's console to redirect all tcp connections to `localhost:8080` to a private address `10.0.2.15:8080` which is in AE1. And in AE2, I should let AE2 connect to `10.0.2.2:8080` which is actually the localhost of host machine.

I understand this structure, but not matter how I try, I just cannot make it work. Don't know what's wrong with it. Further, I cannot even access the server in AE1 from my host machine. I guess I just haven't really redirect the `localhost:8080` to `10.0.2.15:8080` successfully.

My OS is: Linux Mint 19

Android SDK: 28

And help is apperciated!